# IIS is returning 404 errors for ASPX pages that exist (aka DllRegisterServer entry point was not found)

Tags: .net, iis

I'm having problems refreshing .Net 2.0 with IIS 6.

I have been able to successfully execute "aspnet_regiis.exe -i", but when I try to register the aspnet_isapi.dll:

```
regsvr32 “C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"
```

I get the error

> C:\Windows..\aspnet_isapi.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.
>
> The file cannot be registered.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?  Google hasn't been very helpful.

**Edit:** My problem is actually that IIS isn't serving my webpages properly - that is, it's returning 404s when I try to request .aspx files that I know exist.

I can access .gif and .js files OK, but I can't access .aspx or other .Net files.  I know this is related to .Net being properly configured with IIS, and the above commands are supposed to be the solution, but the second command doesn't work.

**@aaronjensen**: Your command to register scripts worked successfully, and investigating the logs I find that I'm getting an entry for my failed request with status 404, substatus 2.

Microsoft tells me this because "[Lockdown Policy Prevents This Request](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0f4ac79a-dc2b-4a5f-89c1-d57266aa6ffe.mspx?mfr=true)".

> If a request is denied because the
> associated ISAPI or CGI has not been
> unlocked, a 404.2 error is returned.

Which I assume is due to the isapi DLL in my original query being denied?

Comment: aspnet_isapi.dll isn't a COM DLL, it's an IIS ISAPI filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I think the problem was caused by a step that is missed by the script when you refresh ASP.Net 2.0 with IIS 6.

I managed to resolve this using the following steps:

- Refresh the install using `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -s /w3svc/1/root`
- Enable ASP.Net Web Service Extension in the IIS 6 Management Console - it looks like the extension was not enabled by default in IIS, hence the 404.2 [Lockdown Policy Prevents This Request](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0f4ac79a-dc2b-4a5f-89c1-d57266aa6ffe.mspx?mfr=true) errors that I was seeing.  Instructions to [enable the ASP.Net webservice extension](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596ff388-bc4c-472f-b029-aea2b0418bea.mspx?mfr=true) are on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to register that. Try this as well:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -s /w3svc/1/root

If IIS is still giving you issues, check your event log and google the error there. You'll get hits.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the error, it means either:

1 The DLL does not need to be registered

or

2 The DLL is corrupt

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the credential that IIS server is running under.
2. Check for the AppPool user permission.

Answer (score 0):

At first try all the following

1. aspnet_regiis.exe -i
2. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -s /w3svc/1/root
3. regsvr32 “C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"

If it doesnt fix the problem, check event log in computer management because it could also be another issue. 
My case was an impersonation issue, but it only started to show up in event viewer after i did the aspnet_regiis.